# PHP,mysqli : Dynamic prepared statement not works

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I need to create dynamic queries for a webpage. The users can select what categories they want to search in (the column names in the SQL database) and what are the values they are looking for. I run through some similar posts on stackoverflow and other sites, but I wasn't able to find a solution. I use the code below (It's for testing, so the category I wrote in the category names and the values). In case I don't try to bind the parameters dynamicly the query works well, I can print the values of the $tester array. What could be the solution for this problem? I guess the problem is with the 'call_user_func_array...' part.

```
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
//The category names and variable names
$cat1 = "LCVAR";
$cat2 = "APOLG";
$LCVAR = "KALOCSA";
$APOLG = "magyar";
//creating the statement
$statement = "SELECT VNEV,KNEV FROM TORZS WHERE ";
$statement = $statement . " " . $cat1 . " ". "=?". " ". "AND" . " ";
$statement = $statement . " " . $cat2 . " ". "=?";
//SELECT VNEV,KNEV FROM TORZS WHERE LCVAR =? AND APOLG =?
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$statement);
$a_params = array();
$a_param_type = array("s","s");
$a_bind_params = array($cat1 => $LCVAR,$cat2 => $APOLG);
$param_type = '';
// creating array for call_user_function_array
$n = count($a_param_type);
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
$param_type .= $a_param_type[$i];
} 
$a_params[] = &$param_type;
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
$a_params[] = &$a_bind_params[$i];
}
call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'mysqli_stmt_bind_param'),$a_bind_params);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = array();
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result['VNEV'], $result['KNEV']);
$tester = array();
while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
$tester[] = array($result['VNEV'],$result['KNEV']) ;
}
```

EDIT 1:

Result of `print_r($stmt)` :

```
  mysqli_stmt Object 
     ( [affected_rows] => 0 
       [insert_id] => 0 
       [num_rows] => 0 
       [param_count] => 2 
       [field_count] => 2 
       [errno] => 0 
       [error] => 
       [error_list] => Array ( ) 
       [sqlstate] => 00000 
       [id] => 1 )
```

Result of `print_r($a_bind_params)` :

```
      Array ( [LCVAR] => KALOCSA
              [APOLG] => magyar )
```

Comment: What's the problem? "not works" is very vague. What have you done to debug it? Have you looked at the generated queries before you pass them to `mysqli_stmt_prepare` to see if they are right?

Comment: Yes, I checked the queries. If I don't try binding parameters dynamicly and I give the parameters in a 'static' statement, everything works fine. I guess the problem could be with the 'call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'mysqli_stmt_bind_param'),$a_bind_params)' part.

Comment: I wrote before that the query itself works fine in this state. The problem starts when I want to use dynamic parameter binding and I use call_user_func_array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PHP Manual page for `bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

> Note:
>
> Care must be taken when using mysqli_stmt_bind_param() in conjunction with call_user_func_array(). Note that
>   mysqli_stmt_bind_param() requires parameters to be passed by
>   reference, whereas call_user_func_array() can accept as a parameter a
>   list of variables that can represent references or values.

Beyond this no one can give you a clearer solution because you need to tell us exactly what the problem is, what your [PHP error log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) is telling you and what your [MySQLi stmt error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php) says.

It may also be helpful to yourself and to us if you can output what your SQL query actually is (`print_r($stmt)`) as well as what your bound parameters actually are (`print_r($a_bind_params)`) .

Edit your question and add these details and I'm sure a solution will then be obvious.

---

P.s As referenced by Fred-ii you can simplify your `$statement` with:

```
 $statement = $statement . " " . $cat1 . " ". "=?". " ". "AND" . " ";
```

becoming:

```
 $statement .= " " . $cat1 . " ". "=?". " ". "AND" . " ";
```

And applying this for each time (twice I can see) that your declaring of a variable value contains the variables preceeding value, that's what the `.=` syntax does for you.

Comment: In this case what sould I do to solve this problem? I'm quite new to PHP.

Comment: Do what I have advised in my answer, set out what your MySQLi errors are and what your PHP errors are, and then search Stack Overflow for a solution to the `bind_param` issue, if this is the principle error, you will not be the first person to have this issue. @IstvánBarna

Comment: Thanks! Result of  print_r($stmt) : mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 2 [field_count] => 2 [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 1 )   result of print_r($a_bind_params) : Array ( [LCVAR] => KALOCSA [APOLG] => magyar )

Comment: @IstvánBarna edit your question and update these details into your question. It's hard to read code in comments.

Comment: @IstvánBarna I saw, that's good. Your update shows there are no errors in the SQL, read `[errno] => 0` so you need to find if your error is in the PHP code